# How can I make an iPhone reel like in FlickFishing?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator, iphone

I'm new in iPhone development, and I want to make a custom Reel/Spinner like the Reel in many iPhone fishing games, and I want capture the touch events, such as if the reel is moved to the right/left.

Where should I start?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at using [OpenGL ES](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

On the other hand, you can often get very good results with just old fashion "flipbook" animation created by simply displaying slightly different images in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just starting out, I would suggest you go over the [MoveMe application tutorial](http://17.254.2.129/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Creating_an_iPhone_App/index.html). It will teach you many of the fundamentals of detecting touch events and responding using animations. If you need another sample, you can also have a look at the [Touches sample](http://17.254.2.129/iphone/library/samplecode/Touches/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007435).

Once you feel comfortable with detecting touch events, I would look into [Core Animation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html). The [Cookbook](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_Cookbook/Introduction/Introduction.html) has a lot of examples on how to do many different tasks. The [Animation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Introduction/Introduction.html) also has some valuable information as to how to do various types of animations.

If you have any specific questions while figuring things out, post them here, and welcome to Stack Overflow!